# Smallest positive integer that can be expressed as a linear combination of two integers

Tags: number-theory

I've recently gotten in number theory, using Theory of Numbers by Andrew Adler as a starting point and came across a theorem that states,

Suppose a and b are not 0, let d = (a, b). Then d is the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as a linear combination of a and b.

Is the converse true, i.e. if I find an integer that is the smallest positive integer which is a linear combination of two integers a and b, then it must be the greatest common divisor of a and b? For example, if I found out 1 = xa + yb for some integer x and b, must 1 be the greatest common divisor, since it is the smallest positive integer possible?

Comment: Consider the case where $\gcd(a,b) \neq 1$ and what that would say about what would need to be factors of $xa + yb$ for any integers $x$ and $b$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan gcd(a, b) itself would divide all the linear combinations of xa + yb, meaning it would also divide the smallest one, where gcd(a, b) is less than or equal to it right? How would I go around proving that gcd(a, b) is equal to the linear combination?

Comment: A small correction to my comment is that the end should say "$x$ and $y$".

Comment: As $\gcd(a,b)$ is a positive integer and it must divide all linear combinations of $xa + yb$, then how can any positive value be smaller, as it would mean that any such smaller value divided by $\gcd(a,b)$ would be a non-integral fraction, which contradicts what it means for $\gcd(a,b)$ to divide the value.  I hope this is fairly clear.

Comment: I understand that there are no positive values that are less than the gcd(a, b) itself, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the fact that the smallest linear combination of a and b must be the greatest common divisor of both.

Comment: During my years of tutoring, I found that when a student doesn't understand one approach, sometimes they do when a different one is used.  I suggest you check other explanations online, in books and anything else offered here, with I believe one of them fairly likely to work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an equivalence.   That is, we have an if and only if.

For the "converse", recall that we have that by *Bezout's identity*,  $(a,b)$ can be written as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ (this involves the Euclidean algorithm). So if $d$ is the smallest  number that has this property, we have $d\le (a,b)$.  But of course $d\ge (a,b)$, since any number dividing $a$ and $b$ divides $d$ (by the fact that $d$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$). So $d=(a,b)$.